# Is defining the length of an array with a macro "excellent practice"?

Tags: c, arrays, macros

I'm working through a book called [C Programming: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504) and in the first section discussing arrays, the author states:

> using a macro to define the length of an array is excellent practice

Then uses the brief example:

```
#define N 10
...
int a[N];
```

I understand that it has something to do with being able to go back into the source code of the program and change the value, and making it a macro maybe makes it easier for the programmer, but I'm not certain. **Why** is this an excellent practice, or is it objective?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good practice because

- the array size obviously has to be hard-coded
- but it shouldn't have a magic number injected directly into the source code
- therefore, a macro is a good way to give it a readable name and remove it from the source

That being said I'm not sure I agree this is the best way. An enum also works and avoids some of the problems with macros (e.g. harder to overwrite and silently compile). And IIRC a `const int` works as well.

For reference this compiles with `cc`:

```
const int s = 1;
int a[s];


int main() {
return 0;
}
```

> Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
>   Thread model: posix

Comment: Is there any noticeable performance difference (or any other difference) between the value being pulled from the macro or just using an actual integer value?

Comment: @hancsu there is no difference in runtime between `N` and `10`, becuase there is actually no more `N` after compiation. `N` is simple alias for `10`

Comment: Ah, now I see. I was just worried that with the book getting on a bit, age wise, that the best practices then may not be used now. Thanks to both of you for clearing that up.

Comment: @hancsu you don't know how macros work. You don't "pull" from a macro. They're precompiled ("PRE"-compiled) directly into your code. That's also why they're so dangerous - they're not any smarter than text substitution. You could write a #define-supporting preprocessor yourself.

Comment: @hancsu I see your concern, which is why I explained ways that I think are better than using macros. But I at least tried to explain what's good about the approach.

Comment: @djechlin `const int` does not work in C. Objects of type `const int` are still objects and cannot be used to specify the size of a (non VLA) array.

Comment: That is a VLA, @djechlin. Try compiling with `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors` options (C89 didn't have VLAs) ... or use `s` in a `case` statement: it will not work because `case` statements need constants.

Comment: Even under C99, VLAs have to be at block-scope or function prototype scope, so the actual code in the answer is invalid, even if it would be OK if `a` were within a block. clang will warn about this with `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very good practice, the C language specification itself says to NEVER bury constants into code, but to define them with meaningful names. There are a few ways to do it, macros (my personal favorite since they use no memory), globals (use memory and can be modified), constant globals (use memory but never change).

Comment: spending 4 bytes of memory per program invocation is worth avoiding runtime errors in almost all situations. Your preference for macros speaks of premature optimization.

Comment: I work in environments with less than a megabyte of memory. That is why it is my preference. The better choices are macros (the C way) or const type (the c++ way).

Comment: The prob is that you can't use a global in an array definition as the size. It must be a compile time constant (unless you use C99).

Comment: @PeterSchneider it compiled with cc. `(clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: @djechlin: No contradiction: "By default, Clang builds C code according to the C99 standard" (http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#c).

Comment: Sorry, I don't suggest using clang.

Answer (score 2):

A major reason to use macros instead of a constant integer literal is that when a value is used in multiple places in code, it's much easier to update a single macro value than to go through and find all of a value's uses to update them.

For example, consider the following code:

```
int a[10];
...
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
...
myFunc(a, 10); // 10 indicates the size of the array
```

If you decide later on to change the size of the array, you have to go through and find every instance of `10` where it is used to indicate the size. However, if we do this:

```
#define N 10
int a[N];
...
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
...
myFunc(a, N); // N indicates the size of the array
```

All you have to do is change the value of N to some new number to change the size of the array, and all of your other code will work correctly.

As far as performance, using a macro will be just as fast as hard-coded constant values, since macros are simply a text-based substitution. During compile time, if the macro `N` has the value `10`, then every instance of `N` in the C source code will be changed to `10` before actually being compiled.

Comment: I know you're just trying to write an example, but those for-loops are dead wrong practice. Should always be `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)` which solves this problem perfectly. (It fails on zero size arrays. Which should be okay.)

Comment: ...same for `myFunc` actually. The example you actually want is something like `Foo foo[10]; int someFooProperty[10];` where for some reason you need two corresponding arrays.

Comment: I prefer `int a[N]; myFunc(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));`, but do use `N` as in `int *a = malloc(N * sizeof(*a)); myFunc(a, N)`.

Comment: Using `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` only works in the same context in which the array is created, so if you're doing that on an array passed via a pointer, it's invalid.

Comment: @millinon Is there any alternative? Aside from the original i < N

Comment: What do you mean by an alternative to `i < N`? If you iterate through an array, you have to have some way of knowing the array's size, whether that's `10` or `N`.

Comment: @millinon I mean an alternative to the example posted by djechlin that fails on arrays that have a size of 0, as you stated that it only works under certain conditions.

Comment: If the array size is zero, then `i<0` will return false, and the loop will not run. The `sizeof` method will likely still work, since the compiler will know the type (and size) of `a[0]`.