# As a beginner, is looking too "in-depth" a bad idea?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I've recently attempted to start learning the C programming language, this question isn't specific to that one language though, or any language for that matter. I've found that I regret asking for information/best practices as early in the learning process as I have, simply because I'm receiving **too much** information.

As an example, I asked a question related to arrays in C:

[Is defining the length of an array with a macro "excellent practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327579/is-defining-the-length-of-an-array-with-a-macro-excellent-practice)

What I found was, I received the answer I was looking for; but, I also received a slew of other information, that, as a beginner was absolutely over my head. I then regretted asking in the first place because I found myself worrying about things that I probably shouldn't know/care about at this stage in the learning process.

I guess what I'm asking is: do you think worrying about best practices and language caveats when I'm a beginner will be harmful to me, or is it encouraged? I find myself getting lost reading questions under the 'c' tag, of which I was trying to use to improve my knowledge, but now I'm bogged down and not making any *real progress* because of all the little details in comments/answers etc.

Comment: This is not an easy question in my opinion. I would say: It is a good idea to think about good practies in this early stage, but first you should get used to the language. So learning and understanding the language should be the first goal. After you feel like you can handle the language, you can think about best practice approaches. This is, of course, only my opinion.

Comment: See, I've been working through this book, seeing things that look perfectly normal to me (i.e. a function called gets()), in my tiny knowledge of programming, yet when I go look something like gets() up on the Internet for more information, I'm greeted with site after site, after answer after answer, claiming that it's unsafe. For one thing, I don't even know what would make something unsafe, but it's obviously not a good thing, which kind of steers me away from using it, but ironically, as a beginner, I don't know any alternative. I find myself in a bit of a pickle.

Comment: If you're reading a book that recommends using `gets()` then I think you're reading a bad book. `gets()` is unsafe because it can allow a hacker to take total control of the computer your code is running on. If your computer is a server, this would be especially bad - any mistake made with `gets()` is like enabling remote desktop/vnc access without any password needed for the admin account.

Comment: Something to keep in mind when learning C, is that it is not used for typical programming these days. For example, all string programming should be done with a UTF-8 compatible library. You should not be using standard strings, you should be using something like `NSString` on iOS or an equivalent on Windows/Linux. I write C code almost every day, but I hardly ever create a standard C string.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I appreciate the response, but that is exactly the type of thing my question is aimed at. I've looked at multiple books, and none of them have any alternative to that particular example. The general consensus seems to be; use what I give you, then learn about that stuff once you know the language, which is what I'm tending towards at the minute. It's just really de-motivating trying to learn every detail about something that I probably won't need or look at for another 6 months/1 year when I'm writing half-decent programs for my own use.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Another thing I must add is, if gets() is so bad, why isn't it removed from the language entirely? I've no knowledge at all of the way languages and their standards are controlled, but I know of deprecated functions in PHP etc. Why can't the same be done here?

Comment: Because making `gets()` "safe" would take a few nanoseconds and consume a tiny bit of electricity every single time it gets executed, and there are times when the performance hit is unacceptable. C is full of problems that other languages do not have, and it is also the reason why C is still used, because some problems cannot be solved without hurting performance. `gets()` is only dangerous when the programmer makes a mistake. It should be avoided, but that doesn't mean it should never be used.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Ah, that makes a lot more sense, thanks for the explanation. Although from what I understand so far, a lot of the C language seems to rely on the fact that the programmer knows what they're doing, rather than a higher level language that is more forgiving. Of course I could be completely wrong in that assumption.

Comment: Every language relies on the programmer knowing what they are doing. C just bites you harder when you make a mistake. You have to know what you're doing in every language. It's not that hard, looking into it in depth is the right way to go, but don't expect to learn everything quickly, it takes years.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I think that may be my problem, I'm trying to take everything in at once rather than pace myself. At least I know my downfall now so I can get on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not a bad thing, per se, as learning of advanced matters ahead of time can really help you along the road. This isn't even confined to computer science; I, for example, find myself in this position all the time when cooking a new dish or studying relatively advanced mathematics. Of course, if all the little details and super-technical stuff are stressing you out, by all means, take a step back and breathe, try and focus on the task at hand. You can always return to the more advanced topics later!

On the specific question of learning the standard practices and caveats of a given language, I personally recommend it. First of all, doing so can keep you from developing bad habits. Knowing the strengths and weaknesses of a given language are rather important, and can influence you later on. If you have one or two things you *really* hate about C, you can try another language in the future that addresses those issues. The sooner you acquaint yourself with such matters the sooner you can make a decision.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I really should stop stressing over it. It's just things like I mentioned in my comment above, like the example of gets(). I go look it up, find that it's "unsafe", then when I try to find out why, I see that it's into a level of detail that I could only comprehend if I knew the language fully. It's like a never ending loop of a problem. I try to find more out about something -> I can't find more about it until I know more -> I can't know more till I find out more about it. :(

Comment: Hey, it may be a vicious cycle, but at least it's an educational one :D

Comment: That's the thing though, at this point, it really isn't. I've found the more I look into it, the more I get bogged, down and the less useful information I take on-board. At this point in my learning, I'm not experienced enough to know what to ignore and what to take on board.

Comment: Well it really does boil down to how familiar you are with C at the moment, and how familiar you are with general technical terminology that you run across. If you aren't experienced enough to filter through the exceedingly technical stuff, by all means, ignore it and just focus on making your program(s) work. You can always come back later and figure out how it works and how to make it work even better, and delve into one or two specific topics at a time if there's more you need/want to know. Of course, feel free to jot down any subjects you want to read up on later as you go along.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it's my own fault for getting bogged down in the end. I'm a techie, that's for sure, I understand a lot of programming concepts, just not how to implement them, or why certain things work. For example, I understand the basic concept of recursion, but I don't understand the technicalities behind how you can call a function from within itself when the function hasn't even finished running. Thanks for the replies anyway, I'll just go do some more learning and hope I don't come across anything that I'll end up on SO for ;)

Comment: Quite frankly you should be pleased that you're asking the sort of questions that lead to elaborate responses, and that you're capable of looking into the nitty-gritty of everything. I understand that you get anxious about not knowing whatever it is you don't know, but try and relax. Knowledge is largely a product of time, so it might take a while, but eventually you *will* have, at the very least, a casual grasp of all that is currently stressing you out.

Comment: I must have mild OCD or something. If I'm reading a book about C (I've looked at a few, but stuck to one in the end), and the author says something to the effect of: "but we'll go over this in more detail at a later stage in the book". My mind is always like "DO IT NOW DAMNIT". Which inevitably, leads me to the Internet, and so far looking up C topics on the Internet has done nothing but made my brain and eyes hurt. ;)